# Android app crashes on Launching, not getting crash report on crashalytics

Tags: android, crash, runtime, launch

My android app on release, suddenly get crashing, PFB attached screenshot from Google play console crash:
[image: Crash report]

Can you guys help me to understand, what is cause of crash actually?

- It crashes on below nougat version, but not on all device.
- Status bar color has some alpha value less than 1.0, following colors are used for toolbar & title bar respectively.

  #daef0b0f
  #9cef0b0f

Comment: Try changing the theme in manifest file for your Launcher activity.

Comment: Do you have alpha in your theme colors? You shouldn't - the colors should be fully opaque. http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ActivityManager.java#982

Comment: It might be the theme but also maybe the device the app runs on has some tweaks that make your app crash. Does it crash on all devices regardless of android version?

Comment: @laalto : Please see my updated question.

Comment: @csanonymous : Please see my updated question.

Comment: This issue is definitely related to a theme ... I think you are facing this issue only on Oppo devices right?

Comment: @akshay_shahane : Facing issue on oppo, MI, samsung , HTC phones as per reports.

Comment: Check your themes @saggy. problem is most likely to be there we faced the same problem few months before our was crashing only on Oppo devices

Comment: The colors `#daef0b0f #9cef0b0f` both have transparency. Remove the `da` and `9c` (or set to `ff`).

Comment: @laalto : according to your post, app should not have alpha color in title bar & toolbar?

Comment: The colorPrimary in your app theme should have the alpha channel at 0xff.